# Spyder version 5.1.5 issues

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I had problems installing Spyder version 5.1.5. I followed all the steps outlined by @Carlos Cordoba which I have listed below:

```
conda remove spyder
conda remove python-language-server
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=5.1.5
```

As soon as I did the above, my Anaconda installation was broken really badly. It is taking almost 8 hours to repair. If I had known, I should have remained with my jupyter notebooks but I decided to be adventurous with Spyder. Anyone knows any other fix for this?

Comment: I would be faster to just do a clean anaconda install and then use [After conda update, python kernel crashes when matplotlib is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69786885/7758804)

Comment: I would also like to update. But as soon as I do it I loose a lot of libraries [numpy, scipy, sympy ..]!

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating to Spyder 5.0.5 first then updating to 5.1.5 next. Maybe it might work. I managed to successfully update to 5.1.5 from 5.0.5 days ago without encountering any issues. Unfortunately, now that I have uninstalled and reinstalled Python and Anaconda in my newer laptop, even I too encountered this difficulty in updating to 5.1.5 straight from 4.2.5. Updating to Spyder 5.0.5 from 4.2.5 worked, but then updating to 5.1.5 didn't.