# After conda update, python kernel crashes when matplotlib is used

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, conda, freetype

I have create this simple env with `conda`:

```
conda create -n test python=3.8.5 pandas scipy numpy matplotlib seaborn jupyterlab
```

The following code in `jupyter lab` crashes the kernel :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplot()
```

I don't face the problem on `Linux`. The problem is when I try on `Windows 10`.

There are no errors on the `jupyter lab` console (where I started the server), and I have no idea where to investigate.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

### Update 2021-11-06

- The default `pkgs/main` channel for `conda` has reverted to using `freetype 2.10.4` for Windows, per [main / packages / freetype](https://anaconda.org/main/freetype).
- If you are still experiencing the issue, use `conda list freetype` to check the version: `freetype != 2.11.0`

  - If it is `2.11.0`, then change the version, per the solution, or `conda update --all` (providing your default channel isn't changed in the `.condarc` config file).

### Solution

- If this is occurring after installing [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/), updating `conda` or [`freetype`](https://freetype.org/) since Oct 27, 2021.
- Go to the `Anaconda` prompt and downgrade `freetype 2.11.0` in any affected environment.

  - `conda install freetype=2.10.4`
- Relevant to any package using `matplotlib` and any IDE

  - For example, `pandas.DataFrame.plot` and `seaborn`
  - Jupyter, Spyder, VSCode, PyCharm, command line.

---

### Discovery

- An issue occurs after updating with the most current updates from `conda`, released Friday, Oct 29.
- After updating with `conda update --all`, there's an issue with anything related to `matplotlib` in any IDE (not just `Jupyter`).

  - I tested this in `JupyterLab`, `PyCharm`, and `python` from the command prompt.
  - PyCharm: `Process finished with exit code -1073741819`
  - JupyterLab: kernel just restarts and there are no associated errors or Traceback
  - command prompt: a blank interactive matplotlib window will appear briefly, and then a new command line appears.
- The issue seems to be with `conda update --all` in `(base)`, then any plot API that uses `matplotlib` (e.g. `seaborn` and `pandas.DataFrame.plot`) kills the kernel in any environment.
- I had to reinstall Anaconda, but **do not do an update of `(base)`**, then my other environments worked.
- I have not figured out what specifically is causing the issue.
- I tested the issue with `python 3.8.12` and `python 3.9.7`
- Current Testing:

  - Following is the `conda` revision log.
  - Prior to `conda update --all` this environment was working, but after the updates, plotting with `matplotlib` crashes the python kernel

```py
  2021-10-31 10:47:22  (rev 3)
     bokeh  {2.3.3 (defaults/win-64) -> 2.4.1 (defaults/win-64)}
     click  {8.0.1 (defaults/noarch) -> 8.0.3 (defaults/noarch)}
     filelock  {3.0.12 (defaults/noarch) -> 3.3.1 (defaults/noarch)}
     freetype  {2.10.4 (defaults/win-64) -> 2.11.0 (defaults/win-64)}
     imagecodecs  {2021.6.8 (defaults/win-64) -> 2021.8.26 (defaults/win-64)}
     joblib  {1.0.1 (defaults/noarch) -> 1.1.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     lerc  {2.2.1 (defaults/win-64) -> 3.0 (defaults/win-64)}
     more-itertools  {8.8.0 (defaults/noarch) -> 8.10.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     pyopenssl  {20.0.1 (defaults/noarch) -> 21.0.0 (defaults/noarch)}
     scikit-learn  {0.24.2 (defaults/win-64) -> 1.0.1 (defaults/win-64)}
     statsmodels  {0.12.2 (defaults/win-64) -> 0.13.0 (defaults/win-64)}
     sympy  {1.8 (defaults/win-64) -> 1.9 (defaults/win-64)}
     tqdm  {4.62.2 (defaults/noarch) -> 4.62.3 (defaults/noarch)}
     xlwings  {0.24.7 (defaults/win-64) -> 0.24.9 (defaults/win-64)}
```

- The issue seems to be `freetype`

  - Downgrading from `2.11.0` to `2.10.4` resolved the issue and made the environment work with `matplotlib`
- Went to post a bug report and discovered there is [[Bug]: Matplotlib crashes Python #21511](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21511)

Answer (score 4):

For anybody that downgrading to `freetype=2.10.4` didn't work. In my case the issue happened after installing the new version of `scikit-learn=1.11` from `conda-forge` channel. After trying out many options the following worked for me:

- reinstall `numpy` from `main/pkg` to `conda-forge` channel
- reinstall `mkl` package `conda -c intel mkl`
- reinstall `matplotlib=4.3` from `conda-forge`

It's quite a drastic measure, since you have to reinstall all dependecies that rely on NumPy (Pandas, TensorFlow etc.), but it was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE March 2nd 2023:**

This is the Output captured from my kernel after dying:

> OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5md.dll
> already initialized.
>
> OMP: Hint: This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have
> been linked into the program. That is dangerous since it can degrade
> performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do is to
> ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the process,
> e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any library.
> As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can set the
> environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to
> continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce
> incorrect results. For more information, please see
> http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.

I was facing the similar problem, I fixed it by deleting the libiomp5md.dll duplicate file from Anaconda environment folder path this directory:

C:\Users\your-user-name.conda\envs\your_env_name\Library\bin\libiomp5md.dll

actually downgrading `freetype` didn't work for me.
you can add 'libiomp5md.dll' back to Original file,it can fix kernel died temporarily but caused OMP error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after a fair amount of investigation and troubleshooting, the fix was pretty straight forward:

```
conda update -c anaconda numpy

conda upgrade -c conda-forge matplotlib
```

After that it ran fine and my visuals plotted without issue.

Comment: This is a terrible option. It has the effect of **removing 45 packages**, **downgrading hundreds of packages** and switching them from `pkgs/main` to the `anaconda` [channel](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo), it then upgrades and switches then to the `conda-forge` [channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/repo). And this only works because `conda-forge` hasn't yet incorporated `freestyle 2.11.0` into the [channel feedstock](https://conda-forge.org/feedstock-outputs/). The better option is the accepted answer, which only changes the version of the single problem package.

Comment: This worked for me. But I read @TrentonMcKinney 's comment too late.
Any way to roll back to the updated version that does not involve reinstalling?

Comment: @Nando Do `conda update --all`, which will use the default `pkgs/main` channel, and then apply the accepted answer.

Comment: @Nando Conda tracks revisions. See `conda list --revisions`; rollback with `conda install --revision <n>`.

Comment: The query was re a simple conda env, which I have provided a simple and valid fix. It is not intended for your base conda env.