# plotting with seaborn results in python kernel crashing

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, seaborn, jupyter

I'm using Anaconda on Win10, when I'm trying execute simple cell on localhost containing seaborn, I get dead kernel message withing 5 second, after rebooting it is just infinity execution of sns plot cell. [For example in titanic dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFUNQ.png)

There is no such problem using Collab or Binder [No problem with collab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnBuO.png);
[No problem using Binder, online Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh8Hp.png)

Seems that I'm missing something obvious.
Code:

```
import seaborn as sns       
import pandas        
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt       
df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')       
df.head()           
sns.countplot(x='sex',data=df)
```

Comment: Can you check the version of your seaborn, python and jupyter version? You can use `conda list` in the terminal to check it.

Comment: @VinsonCiawandy, Seaborn is 0.11.2, python is 3.9.7, for jupyter:
jupyter  1.0.0 ;         
jupyter_client    7.0.1   ;
jupyter_console   6.4.0   ;
jupyter_core   4.8.1  ;
jupyterlab_pygments  0.1.2 ;

As i've reinstalled OS couple of hours ago, i suppose these are latest versions

Comment: Can you try downgrading the python version maybe to `3.8.10` or `3.7.9`? Even today(late 2021) Python 3.9 is not yet adopted since it have many compability issue with libraries.

Comment: Did you update `conda` this weekend?  (e.g. `conda update --all`)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/69786885/7758804

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney  I've recreated env with Python 3.7.10, worked fine for me, Thank you very much sir!