# how to draw graph? (x=datetime, y=price)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I type some code to show the relationship between price and datetime about bitcoin.So I want to draw the graph to show them BUT it fail, i dont know the reason, please give me some tips,thanks a lot.

**below is my code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\downloads\BTC-USD.csv', date_parser = True)


df.columns = ['datetime','open','high','low','close','adj', 'vol']

print(df.head(5))

df.index = df['datetime']




df.datetime=pd.to_numeric(df.datetime,errors='coerce')
df.adj=pd.to_numeric(df.adj,errors='coerce')

print(df[['datetime', 'adj']].plot(kind = 'line', figsize=[20,5]))
```

**below is the terminal result**

```
PS D:\python> python test3.py
0  2020-10-30  13437.874023  ...  13546.522461  30581485201
1  2020-10-31  13546.532227  ...  13780.995117  30306464719
2  2020-11-01  13780.995117  ...  13737.109375  24453857900
3  2020-11-02  13737.032227  ...  13550.489258  30771455468
4  2020-11-03  13550.451172  ...  13950.300781  29869951617

[5 rows x 7 columns]
PS D:\python> python test3.py
     datetime          open  ...           adj          vol
0  2020-10-30  13437.874023  ...  13546.522461  30581485201
1  2020-10-31  13546.532227  ...  13780.995117  30306464719
2  2020-11-01  13780.995117  ...  13737.109375  24453857900
3  2020-11-02  13737.032227  ...  13550.489258  30771455468
4  2020-11-03  13550.451172  ...  13950.300781  29869951617

[5 rows x 7 columns]
AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
```

Comment: Did you update conda? If so, does this answer your question? [After conda update, python kernel crashes when matplotlib is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69786885/7758804)

Comment: Also if you're plotting from a file, it needs `plt.show()` after `df[['datetime', 'adj']].plot(kind = 'line', figsize=[20,5])`.

Comment: Thankyou very much, After I installed anaconda, I  successly plot the graph. (I failed whiling using pip)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use the print function. Just call

```
df[['datetime', 'adj']].plot(kind = 'line', figsize=[20,5])
```

Comment: I delete the print function, but it still cannot work.