# Networkx - I updated Anaconda and now if I try drawing the graphs with labels on it doesn´t work and restarts the kernel

Tags: python, networkx, draw

I'm new using netowrkx and since I made some updates in Anaconda (but I'm not sure if it was because of that) I been having some weird issue when I try to draw the graphs with the drawing functions of networkx, if I just draw it like, for example, `networkx.draw(G)` or `networkx.draw_circular(G)` there is no problem, but if I turn True "with_labels" like, for example, `networkx.draw(G, with_labels=True)` or `networkx.draw_circular(G, with_labels=True)` it doesn't run and the console gives me the message, on Spyder: "Restarting kernel...", and in Jupyter: "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

At first I thought that it might be and option that is no longer supported or something like that but if I try it on notebook from Google Colab it does works perfectly and draws me the graphs with the labels. Sorry if I'm being dumb, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like it could be related to [this recently introduced bug.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786885/after-conda-update-python-kernel-crashes-when-matplotlib-is-used) Does the solution there work for you?

Comment: It worked, thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After conda update, python kernel crashes when matplotlib is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786885/after-conda-update-python-kernel-crashes-when-matplotlib-is-used)