# Segmentation Fault in matplotlib.pyplot.savefig

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, segmentation-fault, savefig

I am running a set of python scripts on my visual studio code on windows 10. It seems that there is a bug in `matplotlib` package of the anaconda3. Specifically, I notice that saving a figure as a `.png` utilizing `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig` function produces a **segmentation fault** error message as the following. I search alot in the past few days and still could not figure out what is the issue. Specifically, the following explanation ([#12286](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12286/)) helped me to understand the issue but did not give me any workaround. I would need your help on this matter.

**Update1: Here is the content of Plotter module:**

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()
from Utilities import *

class Plotter:
    def __init__(self, lst1: list, lst2: list, lst3: list):
        self.lst1 = lst1
        self.lst2 = lst2
        self.lst3 = lst3

    def plotterFunc(self) -> mpl.pyplot.axes:
        fig, ax = mpl.pyplot.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
        setScaleLabelTickLimit(ax, t3)
        ax.set_ylabel('Intensity [$\\frac{{W}}{{cm^{{2}}}}$]')
        plotter2(ax, x3, self.lst3)
        mpl.pyplot.savefig(PLOT_DIR/'Intensity/Intensity.png', 
                    orientation='landscape', bbox_inches='tight')
        mpl.pyplot.clf()
        
    def plotterFunc2():
        pass
    
    def plotterFunc3():
        pass
```

--Thank you,

> Windows fatal exception: access violation
>
> Current thread 0x0001fb6c (most recent call first):
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 240 in get_text_width_height_descent
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 306 in _get_layout
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 903 in get_window_extent
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1068 in 
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1068 in _get_tick_bboxes
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1142 in draw
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 51 in draw_wrapper
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 132 in _draw_list_compositing_images
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py", line 2921 in draw
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_api\deprecation.py", line 431 in wrapper
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
> line 51 in draw_wrapper   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line
> 132 in _draw_list_compositing_images
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
> line 2790 in draw
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 51 in draw_wrapper
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 74 in draw_wrapper
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2230 in print_figure
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py",
> line 78 in print_figure
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
> line 3015 in savefig
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 966 in savefig
> File "c:\Users\username...\Plotter.py", line 41 in plotterFunc

> File "c:/Users/username/.../my_script.py", line 199 in main
> File "c:/Users/username/.../my_script.py", line 211 in

> Segmentation fault

Comment: Plotter.py isnt matplotlib, so the bug is likely elsewhere.  It would be nice to know what Plotter.py is and how it was installed.

Comment: Thank you Jody, Plotter.py is just a utility plotter class I have created myself. Let me see if I can post its content.

Comment: I see now, sorry.  This is also it certainly a bad version of fontconfig on conda for windows.  Update your install .

Comment: I added the Plotter. Do you mean to do "conda update conda" followed by "conda update anaconda"?

Comment: Just try updating fontconfig.

Comment: Sorry freetype.  Relatively sure this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786885/after-conda-update-python-kernel-crashes-when-matplotlib-is-used

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue is resolved.

Comment: I have to downgrade freetype to an earlier version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After conda update, python kernel crashes when matplotlib is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69786885/after-conda-update-python-kernel-crashes-when-matplotlib-is-used)

Comment: Thank you Trenton, the issue is resolved now.