# When I import Seaborn to Jupyter I get the following error: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

When ever I try to import Seaborn into my jupyter notebook I get the following error: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. Ive tried to conda install Seaborn again and restarted everything but continue to have the same error. If I remove the import seaborn the code runs well. Only when I add import seaborn I get the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69788527/7758804

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to include the versions of the Kernel and Seaborn that you are using. Also, include an example that reproduces the problem if you can.