# Any type of visual display kills my Kernel

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

This is an issue I have had all semester, and I have been able to ignore it up until my Final. Whenever I try to run code that shows any type of visual, be it a graph, or bar plot, or anything; it kills my kernel. This happens in both Jupyter Notebook and Jupyter Lab, but I can get visual on Google Colab. I have a Dell Inspiron 7391 2n1 with an Intel CORE i5 10th gen processor. (just in case it is my machine that has the issue.) I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda and the Python packages three or four times with no luck. Below is an example of the code that kills my kernel.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style('whitegrid')

for feature in esports_df.columns:
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
sns.scatterplot(data=esports_df, x=feature, y='TotalUSDPrize',
               hue='TotalUSDPrize', palette='cool', legend=False)
```

What can I do to fix this? Because I really hope I don't have to buy a new computer

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. At the very least, add error messages, logs and whatever you can find to make solving it easier.

Comment: Not really enough information to answer. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69788527/7758804) fix the issue?