# Matplotlib crash even with Freetype 2.10.4 installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, crash

I am experiencing an error similar to that described in a previous thread [https://stackoverflow.com/q/69786885/19537148] where Matplotlib crashes my Jupyter notebook kernel, however I have Freetype v2.10.4 installed in my current environment, using Python 3.7.12.

Has anyone experienced a similar error?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah I'm having this problem right now. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up starting the project over from scratch, due to issues not related to Matplotlib, and then when I tried to plot in the new file it worked just fine.

Comment: I had to reestablish my conda env (luckily I had saved a decent yml file) as my environment got messed up somehow maybe when tried to install cuda as I noted it altered a bunch of other modules.  Working better now for me too.